# system.site.yml not installing correct site settings

Tags: 8, installation, configuration, installation-profiles

performing D8 install through a custom profile, added a system.site.yml like:

```
name: 'Portal Manager'
mail: cms-admin@example.com
slogan: ''
page:
 403: ''
 404: ''
 front: /user
admin_compact_mode: false
weight_select_max: 100
langcode: en
default_langcode: en
```

Its "siblings" system.date and system.cron for example set the correct values upon installation, but the site frontpage and email stays the default..

Any piece of advice?

, thank you

Comment: Did you base the custom profile on the standard profile, because this overwrites the frontpage path in an install hook?

Comment: there is a standard_install() call there.., you are probably right... but why I had this in there in the first place ...?